# how to add MDList(OneLineListItem) in MDDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to add a method that will be called when I press the button.
After the button is called , a `MDDialog` should appear and show a `OneLineListItem` containing some data.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

main = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Press Me'
        on_press: app.open_dia()
'''

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(main)

    def open_dia(self):
        dia = MDDialog()
        dia.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='Im an list item'))
        dia.open()

Example().run()
```